# Increment by 1 in logical vector

Tags: r

I have a logical vector `do_it = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)`

I want TRUE values to be incremented by 1 and output should be `c(0, 1, 0, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take `cumsum` of the vector and multiply it with itself to keep `FALSE` values as 0.

```
do_it = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
cumsum(do_it) * do_it
#[1] 0 1 0 2 3
```

You can also use `replace` :

```
replace(cumsum(do_it), !do_it, 0)
```